# Submit form to disable?

Tags: javascript, forgot-password, one-time-password

I need to make a form with OTP generation,where the number feild will have the OTP button and when user clicks on it the OTP will be send to his registered number given. After entering the OTP the submit button should be enable.Initially the submit button should be hidden How to write a javascript code for this. Help needed.

Comment: please paste a code block what you have tried earlier?

Comment: hi, can you please paste your code here, then it will be easy to read

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I haven't tried with the code. I am confused how to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 2 css class.

1. Hide
2. Show

Hide will make the button's display property as none and show will make it visible.

Initially your submit button will have a css class of hide

In javascript create a click handler on 1'st button. When the user clicks on OPT send button. Change the css class of submit button from hide to show.

Refer to below bin for example

```
var send = document.querySelector(".send");
var sub = document.querySelector(".submit");
send.addEventListener('click', function(){
    sub.classList.remove('hide');
    sub.classList.add('show');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/jucivus/edit?html,css,js,output